# Improving A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Say I am finding a path in a house using A* algorithm. Now the running time could be O(n^2).

I was thinking will it improve the performance if I knew which doors to follow and according I shall apply A* on it i.e. if I have the starting position `S` and final position as `F`, and instead of applying the A* on these two end points, will be be better if I applied the A* on

```
`S` and `A1`
`A1` and `A2`
`A2` and F.
```

Where A1 and A2 are my intermediates(doors) that shall be followed for the shortest path? Will it be worth the improvement to find the intermediates and then follow the path and not just apply A* directly on starting and ending.

Considering it takes linear time to find the intermediates.

Comment: How do you guarantee it takes linear time to find the intermediates? Do you relax the optimality requirement?

Comment: @us2012 yea, that is what will take me linear time to find out, if I have the correct representation of my data. After that I can just move within a room till the intermediates and subsequently reaching the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will help a lot in case the algorithm takes `O(n^2)` behavior at runtime. Instead of one big problem you get two smaller problems with each being 1/4 as expensive to compute.

I'm sure there are pathological cases where it doesn't help or even hurt but in your scenario (house) it would probably help a lot.

I imagine that you are using the fact that one has to go up an elevator or stairs to change floors. That would help A* a lot because the cost function now has to work only within a single floor. It will be very representative of the real cost. In contrast to that the cost function would be greatly underestimating the distance if you wanted to move into the same room but one floor higher. Euclidean distance would fail totally in that case (and the algorithm would degrade into an exhaustive search). First moving to the stairs and then moving from the stairs to the desired room would work much better.

Comment: And assuming if I have only one floor to consider? Will it still be wise enough to find the doors that I should follow from one place to other?

Comment: Well, it may help me with the worst case scenarios maybe? I can apply A* within a room to get to the door, but it will help me with the sense of direction that I need to follow within the floor overall?

Comment: It is likely to help. It will help if it effectively improves the precision of the cost function.